# trouble with displaying data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having two issues this moment

1. I am having trouble displaying the data from my firestore document after the user signs in and they do have a document with data
2. I have a button that lets the user upload a document and I will parse it to extract all important data. That data is then put into the document with Ids, which is basically the userId + what number doc it is belonging to the user. When they upload the data it seems that all data extracted uses the same ID and only the last one extracted gets displayed.

this is my code:

```
const loansRef = firebase.firestore().collection('goals');
const [ courseGoals, setCourseGoals ] = useState([]);
const [goalCounter, setGoalCounter] = useState(0)

//let the user upload doc, what gets called when they press button
const pickDocument = async () => {
        try {
            let input = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
                type: "text/plain",
            });
            setUserOut(await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(input.uri));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        createLoans();
    };
    
    //extracts important info and returns array with all info for one loan
    const fileParser = () => {
        const parsedLoans = [];
        var newUserOut = userOut;

        if (newUserOut.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        //remove the grants
        var grantPos = newUserOut.search("Grant Type:");
        var pos = newUserOut.search("Loan Type:");
        //hopefully just the loans now
        newUserOut = newUserOut.slice(pos, grantPos);

        while (newUserOut.length > 0) {
            var lastPos = newUserOut.lastIndexOf("Loan Type:");
            parsedLoans.push(newUserOut.slice(lastPos, newUserOut.length));
            newUserOut = newUserOut.slice(0, lastPos);
        }
        //console.log('parsed loans: ' + parsedLoans)
        return parsedLoans;
    };

    //where we actually create loans and get the important data for each loan
    const createLoans = () => {
        const newLoans = fileParser();
        const title= 'Loan Amount:$'
        const interest = 'Loan Interest Rate:'

        for(let i =0; i < newLoans.length; i++){
            let loan = newLoans[i]
            let goalTitle=loan.substring(loan.indexOf(title)+title.length,loan.indexOf('Loan Disbursed Amount:'))
            //console.log("goalTitle: " + goalTitle)
            let interestRate = loan.substring(loan.indexOf(interest)+interest.length,loan.indexOf('Loan Repayment Plan Type'))
            //console.log("Interest rate: "+ interestRate)
            let years = 0
            let paidOff = 0

            addGoalHandler(goalTitle,interestRate,years,paidOff)
        }
        return
    
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        getPW()
        let isMounted = true;

        if (isMounted) {
            loansRef.doc(userId).onSnapshot(
                (docSnapshot) => {
                    if(!docSnapshot.exists){console.log('doc doesnt exist, start from scratch')}
                    else{
                        console.log('loaded successfully '+docSnapshot.data())
                        setGoalCounter(docSnapshot.data().loans.length)
                        console.log(goalCounter)
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }
        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
        };
    }, []);

    
    const addGoalHandler = (goalTitle, interestRate, years, paidOff) => {
        //setCourseGoals([...courseGoals, enteredGoal])
        setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
        setCourseGoals((prevGoals) => [
            ...courseGoals,
            {
                id:userId.toString() + goalCounter.toString(),
                value: goalTitle,
                interest: interestRate,
                years: years,
                paidOff: paidOff
            }
        ]);

        addToFB(goalTitle, interestRate,years,paidOff)
        
        //var oldIDS = docIDS 
        //oldIDS.push(userId.toString() + goalCounter.toString())
        //setDocIDS(oldIDS)
        setIsAddMode(false);
    };

    const cancelGoalAdditionHandler = () => {
        setIsAddMode(false);
    };

    const addToFB = async (goalTitle, interestRate, years, paidOff) => {
        //adding data to firebase, takes into account if doc exists already 
        const loadDoc = await loansRef.doc(userId).get()
            .then((docSnapshot)=> {
                if(docSnapshot.exists){
                    loansRef.doc(userId).onSnapshot((docu)=>{
                        const updateLoansArr = loansRef.doc(userId).update({
                            loans: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                                id: userId+goalCounter.toString(),
                                value: goalTitle,
                                interest: interestRate,
                                years: years,
                                paidOff: paidOff
                            })
                        })
                        //setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
                    })
                }
                else{
                    const addDoc = loansRef.doc(userId).set({
                        loans: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                        id: userId+goalCounter.toString(),
                        value: goalTitle,
                        interest: interestRate,
                        years: years,
                        paidOff: paidOff
                    })
                })
                //setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
            }})
            //setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
        
    }

    const removeGoalHandler = async (goalId) => {
        /*
        setCourseGoals((currentGoals) => {
            loansRef.doc(goalId).delete().then(console.log('removed correctly'))
            return currentGoals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId);
        });
        setGoalCounter(goalCounter-1)
        */
        //need to use the value and not the goalId
        const removeGoal = await loansRef.doc(goalId).update({
            goals: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(goalId)
        })
        setCourseGoals((currentGoals)=> {
            return currentGoals.filer((goal)=> goal.id !== goalId)
        })
    };
```

Comment: Is this a Firebase program?

Comment: @MrTech yes it is

Comment: Do you want to know how to accomplish very specific Firebase-related tasks using the API?

Comment: Can you provide the sample output of your code? This will help tracing.